# Stored Procedure Returns null to Result Set

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, resultset, callable-statement

while working on JDBC, I got an issue I have created a table in mysql which contains the employee info Employee_Id,Name,City,Salary and Year_of_joining and i also created a stored procedure to the same database which takes two inputs and update the salary of employees base on the year of joining. Here is the Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc(IN var1, IN var2)
BEGIN
  UPDATE "TABLE" SET Salary=var1+Salary WHERE Year_of_Joining= var2
END
```

Now i Created a database connection through java to mysql database (That connection is being established successfully)

But now, When i execute the query after creating the CallableStatement object and try to convert the current result of callable object to Result set i get null . Please help me with this.
Here is the Code:

```
// Creates connection with java:
Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,pswrd);

// Now Calling the Stored procedure from mysql
CallableStatement col =  con.prepareCall("{call proc(?,?)}");

// gave values to the procedure
col.setDouble(1,20000);
col.setInt(2,2012);
col.execute();

// Returning Result set=null
ResultSet rs = col.getResultSet();
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but ResultSets are returned if you execute a SELECT query... and yours is a stored procedure call.

Comment: yes sir you are right.....i will keep this point in my mind thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Firstly, you have not set the output parameter in your stored procedure.
>
> Like :
>
> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE proc(IN inputParam VARCHAR(255), OUT OutParam INT)...
> ```
>
> Then, to retrieve the values of output parameters (parameters
>   specified as OUT or INOUT when you created the stored procedure), JDBC
>   requires that they be specified before statement execution using the
>   various registerOutputParameter() methods in the CallableStatement
>   interface.
>
> ```
> col.registerOutParameter("OutParam", Types.INTEGER);
> ```

---

> 2. Secondly, UPDATE statements don't return a ResultSet! Only SELECT statements return a ResultSet to operate upon.

Comment: thanks sir...it makes sense . This point needs to be kept in the mind Update statement does not return the ResultSet and sir would you like to elaborate more about the output parameter of stored procedure. I saw a tutorial where that guy got the result set only with the input parameters. He did not have any output parameter at all.

Comment: @sam - For UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE statements return integer as output(like number of affected rows OR -1 in case of failure), but the SELECT statement returns a ResultSet to operate upon as a tabular description is fetched from the database back to the java code. So, you don't need an OUT parameter for obtaining ResultSet in case of SELECT statement.

Comment: that makes sense sir... one more follow up question. Is there any possible way where i can have a resultset to be returned with the UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE statament... And thank you for the help. You answers show your coding skills.

Comment: already did what u just said up over here... glad to interact with you..thanks

Comment: @sam - No, the only way it is possible to fire a select query inside and retrieve the ResultSet using `boolean hadResults = col.execute();
    //
    // Process all returned result sets
    //
    while (hadResults) {
        ResultSet rs = cos.getResultSet();
        // process result set
        ...
        hadResults = col.getMoreResults();
    }`.

Comment: @sam - Also, go carefully through any of the docs; like one of them is https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html